# Run functions from the class itself

Tags: c++

I'm trying to pass any function type inside a class where they will be stored for later usage. The idea is to run the functions from the class itself by using the function someMethod from the class.

The whole code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

namespace problem {
    class storage {
        struct data_base {};

        template <class K>
        struct data: data_base {
            data(const K& v): value_(v) {}
            K value_;
        };

        typedef std::vector<data_base*> container_type;

    public:
        ~storage() {
            while(!this->VData.empty()) {
                delete this->VData.back();
                this->VData.pop_back();
            }
        }
        template <class P>
        inline void push(P v) {
            this->VData.push_back(new data<P>(v));
        }

        template <class P>
         P &push2(void) {
            static_cast<data<P>*>(this->VData[1])->value_(1,1);
        }

        template < class P = void *>
        void someMethod(void)
        {
             // ERROR HERE: Called object type 'void *' is not a function or function pointer
             static_cast<data<P>*>(this->VData[0])->value_(0,0);
        }


        template <class P>
        P &get(int i) {
            return static_cast<data<P>*>(this->VData[i])->value_;
        }
    private:
        container_type VData;
    };
}

bool function(int x, int y)
{
    std::cout << "hello world1"<< std::endl;
    return x < y;
}

bool function2(int x, int y)
{
    std::cout << "hello world2"<< std::endl;
    return x < y;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    problem::storage testStorage;
    testStorage.push(&function);
    testStorage.push(&function2);

    testStorage.someMethod<>();
    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting this error: **Called object type 'void *' is not a function or function pointer**. I don't know how to achieve my goal. I hope someone more knowledgeable than me can help me to fix this problem and explain step by step so i can learn from it.

Comment: Why not just use a `std::vector<std::function>>`?

Comment: @JesperJuhl Thanks a lot for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by [Jesper Juhl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5910058/jesper-juhl), you can do this using `std::vector<std::function>`. One thing you have to keep in mind. Because you are creating a vector of `std::function`, for one storage object, the signatures of the functions that are stored will be same.

You can do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

namespace problem {
    // forward declaration
    template<typename T, typename ...U>
    class storage;

    template<typename T, typename ...U>
    class storage<T(U...)> {
        using container_type = std::vector<std::function<T(U...)> >;

    public:
        void push(std::function<T(U...)> v) {
            this->VData.push_back(v);
        }

        T callMethod(int i, U &&...args) {
            // TODO: Bounds check
            return this->VData[i](std::forward<U>(args)...);
        }

    private:
        container_type VData;
    };
}

bool function1(int x, int y) {
    std::cout << "hello world1"<< std::endl;
    return x < y;
}

bool function2(int x, int y) {
    std::cout << "hello world2"<< std::endl;
    return x < y;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    problem::storage<decltype(function1)> testStorage;
    testStorage.push(function1);
    testStorage.push(function2);

    cout << testStorage.callMethod(0, 1, 1);
    cout << testStorage.callMethod(1, 1, 1);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
hello world1
0
hello world2
0
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you add a pure virtual operator() to data_base, implement it in data and then make someMethod a regular function rather than a template.

Right now you would need to know the signature of the function to be called in order to correctly invoke someMethod, by making operator() virtual the call would be made in a context that already knows the type of the stored function (that is, from within data

itself).